# Dig out information with Python re

Tags: python, regex

I want to dig out information from the log files and wrote the script below:

```
import re

file = '''Date,Time,Type,User,Message
Thu Jul 18, 2019 14:18:41.945,EFM,201202      ,Robot picked
Thu Jul 18, 2019 14:18:51.486,DS ,201202      ,Module 1
Thu Jul 18, 2019 14:19:07.747,DS ,201202      ,Door opened
Thu Jul 18, 2019 14:20:08.231,EFM,203204205206,Robot picked
Thu Jul 18, 2019 14:20:08.231,DS ,203204      ,Module 2
Thu Jul 18, 2019 14:20:10.282,DS ,203204      ,Door opened
...
'''

p1 = re.compile(r'\w{3} \w{3} \d\d, \d{4} (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d{3}),EFM,(\d+?\s*?),Robot picked')
p2 = re.compile(r'\w{3} \w{3} \d\d, \d{4} (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d{3}),DS ,(\d+?\s*?),Module 1')
p3 = re.compile(r'\w{3} \w{3} \d\d, \d{4} (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d{3}),DS ,(\d+?\s*?),Door opened')

w_file = r'D:\sample.txt'
lines = file.readlines()
t_file =open(w_file,'w')
info = ['User','Time1','Time2','Time3' ]
t_file.write('{}\n'.format(','.join(item for item in info)))

for line in lines:
    p1_line = re.findall(p1, line.strip())
    p2_line = re.findall(p2, line.strip())
    p3_line = re.findall(p3, line.strip())
    if p1_line and p2_line and p3_line:
        if p1_line[0][1][:3] == p2_line[0][1][:3] and p1_line[0][1][:3] == p5_line[0][1][:3]:
            t_file.write('{},{},{},{}\n'.format(p1_line[0][1].strip(),p1_line[0][0],p2_line[0][0],p3_line[0][0])

t_file.close()
```

When I open the sample.txt file, there is only the 'User,Time1,Time2,Time3' row. Can any find what's wrong in my script?

What I want is like below:

```
User,Time1,Time2,Time3
201202,14:18:41.945,14:18:51.486,14:19:07.747
203204205206,14:20:08.231,14:20:08.231,14:20:10.282
```

Comment: The key to debugging regexes is to build them up a bit at a time – and in Python, to try them out interactively! I would take just the first line of logs (which is the second line of your CSV input) and start playing with extracting Thu, then Thu Jul 18, and so forth until you've figured out where things work and where things are broken. You will quickly find out whether any one of your `re.findall()` expressions is giving you the results you want – let alone all three, which is what your if statement seems to be checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your script is that you are trying to match *all* regular expressions to the same line, and then performing an *and* condition, which of course fails.

Each regular expression works but only for specific lines, hence 2 out of the 3 will return `[]` which evaluates to `False`.

For example, given:

```
 line = 'Thu Jul 18, 2019 14:18:41.945,EFM,201202      ,Robot picked'
```

You will have:

```
p1_line = [('14:18:41.945', '201202      ')]  # match
p2_line = []                                  # no match
p3_line = []                                  # no match
```

Once you `and` these three values, the condition will evaluate to `False` and for this reason nothing will be written to the file:

```
if p1_line and p2_line and p3_line:  # this evaluates to False
```

So, depending on the exact logic you want to implement, you may have to store and remember past matches and build on that.